# How to combine my modifications to a newer version?

Tags: mercurial, diff, patch

Okay, here's my situation:

I'm using an open source software package. Let's say the name is **MyApp**.

Due to my needs, I modified the source code of MyApp **v3.0.2**. It works.

Now, MyApp (upstream) gets updated to **v3.1.0**, and the changelog is interesting, because it mentions some security fixes which I would very much like to apply on mine.

I've tracked v3.0.2 and the subsequent changes using Mercurial. Now, what's the best way to integrate those changes to v3.1.0?

My original plan: Do a diff of my version against 3.0.2, revert to 3.0.2, overwrite with 3.1.0 (and commit), then do a file-by-file analysis of the diff, and apply them by hand.

Do you think there's a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Almost, except that you should be able to let Mercurial handle the diffs.

So the basic workflow would be (similar to yours):

- update your repository to 3.0.2 (`hg update <tag>` – you did tag that version, right?)
- unpack 3.1.0 on top and commit (you might want to tag this as something like `upstream-3.1.0`)
- you now have two heads (see `hg heads`)
- update to your original head
- merge (with fingers crossed)

That's how it's supposed to work, and if the changes you've made don't collide with the upstream changes, it may well work in fact.  Failing that, you'll get a greater or lesser number of conflicts, which you can work through and resolve one by one.

It's probably wisest to clone your repository somewhere else local, and do this in the cloned repository.  That way, if it all goes horribly wrong, you can blow that clone away and start again.  After all's nice and tidy, just push it back to your original.

You may want to put the upstream changes on a different branch; or if that feels like a hassle, just remember to update to `upstream-3.1.0` when the time comes to do the same trick with release 3.1.1, or whatever one comes next.